# Return last line of multiple matching records - Git Bash

Tags: grep, git-bash, tail

I have two files.....

One file contains records:

```
123
456
789
abc
def
ghi
```

Second file contains records:

```
123,a
123,b
456,a
456,b
789,a
789,b
abc,1
abc,2
def,1
def,2
ghi,1
ghi,2
```

Trying to do a grep and tail command that would return the last line of a matching string in file 2 so that the output file would return the following:

```
123,b
456,b
789,b
abc,2
def,2
ghi,2
```

Tried to use the following but it just returns the last line of the last matching record:

```
grep -f file1.txt file2.txt | tail -1 > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$0]; next }$1 in a{ b[$1]=$2 }END{ for(i in b) print i FS b[i] }' file1 FS=',' file2
```

The output:

```
def,2
abc,2
ghi,2
123,b
456,b
789,b
```

---

- `FS=','` - field separator
- `b[$1]=$2` - eventually contains the last 2nd field value for same 1st field values

Comment: Golfing : `awk -F, 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]=1; next }a[$1]{ b[$1]=$2 }END{ for(i in b) print i FS b[i] }'`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou, I would say that that was a little shorter, but not faster